# Using your own domain name with Assembla

Tags: svn, cname, assembla

I'm looking into using Assembla for hosted SVN, is it possible to have the SVN url be a company subdomain instead of using the Assembla domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a [planned](http://feedback.assembla.com/forums/5433-feature-requests/suggestions/164238-domain-masking-assembla-mysite-com?ref=title) feature.

Comment: Sadly, "We cannot offer *.mysite.com addresses because we will not be able to offer SSL on those sites, and SSL is increasingly important. Without SSL, any user of a wireless network is vulnerable to password sniffing and session hijacking. We DO offer mysite.assembla.com, with your own branding, on ALL portfolios, public and private".